# android parse is subscribed to more than one account at the same time

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

greetings i'm trying to add parse notification system to an application i'm working on in my company
first i created a dummy account with my email and added the keys to my android app for testing 
then when i tried to integrate the companies account i removed my keys and added the companies Applicatioin ID and client key and i found that when i send notification from my account it still sends to my application after i've changed the keys to my companies account 
is this normal ?
and if it's normal how can i un-subscribe from my account

Answer (score 0):

It is normal because you haven't unsubscribed the user from the channel.

When you log out the user simply call:

```
ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("thenameofyourchannel");
```

Comment: i did that but it also receives notifications

Comment: That is very weird... Did you try to manually uninstall the application, or in the parse dashboard delete the installation id and/or the device?